# State not updating in application

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

I am trying to get my application to update the state on my header once I sign in. It was initially doing so but stopped after creating a few sample users. I am not sure whether that is a problem with my Firestore settings or some code in the app is causing this, but it is quite frustrating. This error also prevents me from signing out any users, thus the statement below in my App.js file keeps outputting the last user that signed in, even after refreshing the page.

```
console.log('THE USER IS >>> ', authUser)
```

*fbConfig.jsx file*

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'xxxx',
    authDomain: 'xxxx',
    projectId: 'xxxx',
    storageBucket: 'xxxx',
    messagingSenderId: 'xxxx',
    appId: 'xxxx',
    measurementId: 'xxxx'
}

//Init firebase app
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

//init services
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)

export { auth, db }
```

*Login.jsx*

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { auth } from '../../fbConfig'
import {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword
} from 'firebase/auth'
import { icon } from '../../constants'

import './Login.css'

const Login = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const { email, setEmail } = useState('')
    const { password, setPassword } = useState('')

    const signIn = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((auth) => {
                // Signed in
                const user = auth.user
                console.log('success' + user + 'registered')
                navigate('/', { replace: true })
                // ...
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert(error.message)
            })
    }

    const register = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((auth) => {
                // Signed in
                const user = auth.user
                console.log('success' + user + 'registered')
                // ...
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert(error.message)
                // const errorCode = error.code
                // const errorMessage = error.message
            })
    }

    return (
        <div className='login'>
            <div className='login__mainContainer'>
                <Link to='/'>
                    <img className='login__logo' src={icon} alt='Webiste logo' />
                </Link>

                <div className='login__container'>
                    <h1>Sign-in</h1>

                    <form>
                        <div className='login__input'>
                            <h5>E-mail</h5>
                            <input
                                className='login__inputEmail'
                                type='text'
                                value={email}
                                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                            />
                            <span className='login__inputSpan'>* Required</span>
                        </div>

                        <div className='login__input'>
                            <h5>Password</h5>
                            <input
                                className='login__inputPassword'
                                type='password'
                                value={password}
                                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                            />
                            <span className='login__inputSpan'>* Required</span>
                        </div>

                        <button
                            type='submit'
                            className='login__signInButton'
                            onClick={signIn}
                        >
                            Sign In
                        </button>
                    </form>     

                    <button className='login__registerButton' onClick={register}>
                        Create your account
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

*Reducer.jsx file*

```
export const initialState = {
    basket: [],
    user: null
}

// Selector
export const getBasketTotal = (basket) =>
    basket?.reduce((amount, item) => item.price + amount, 0)

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    console.log(action)
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_BASKET':
            return {
                ...state,
                basket: [...state.basket, action.item]
            }
        case 'SET_USER':
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.user
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default reducer
```

*App.js*

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Header, Home, Login } from './components'
import { auth } from './fbConfig'
import { useStateValue } from './contextAPI/StateProvider'

import './App.css'

function App() {
    const [dispatch] = useStateValue()

    useEffect(() => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
            console.log('THE USER IS >>> ', authUser)

            if (authUser) {
                // the user just logged in / the user was logged in
                dispatch({
                    type: 'SET_USER',
                    user: authUser
                })
            } else {
                // the user is logged out
                dispatch({
                    type: 'SET_USER',
                    user: null
                })
            }
        })
    })

    return (
        <Router>
            <div className='app'>
                <Header />
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
                    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

Comment: Typo(s).  `useState()` doesn't return an object, it returns an *array*: `const [ email, setEmail ] = useState('')`  Similar destructuring typos may exist throughout this code.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that change as well after I posted the question and it worked out fine.